# Cordova camera plugin NATIVE_URI returns null in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using following code in my app. when using getPicture it returns null all the time, here is my code sample

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess,onFail,{ quality: 50, destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,allowEdit : true, encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG, targetWidth: 1000,targetHeight: 1000, popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions});
```

> It happening in IOS devices using cordova 3.7.0 and cordova camera plugin 1.0.1

Comment: why are you using the dev version of the plugin? try with the latest release (1.2.0)

Comment: Same problem with that also.

Comment: then open an issue on http://issues.cordova.io/

Comment: It's a bug, there is an issue open for this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6627

Comment: Got  solved the issue in other way. Thank you.

Comment: Can you answer your questions with your solution?

Comment: I have used File_uri and moved to persistent folder . nd made it as toInternalURL().